# Messages are not receiving from aws sqs fifo queue in .net core

Tags: .net, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have used aws toolkit in .net to fetch messages from aws sqs in lambda function but messages are not coming.In these code sqs console is also coming empty on cloudwatch and same receiveMessageResponse is also coming empty.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Amazon;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.SQS;
using Amazon.SQS.Model;


 [assembly: 
LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

    namespace AWSLambda1
     {
     public class Function
     {

    /// <summary>
    /// A simple function that takes a string and does a ToUpper
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var sqs = new AmazonSQSClient();
        System.Console.Write("sqs", sqs);
        var queueUrl = "myqueueUrl";
        var receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest{ QueueUrl = queueUrl};
        var receiveMessageResponse = sqs.ReceiveMessageAsync(receiveMessageRequest);
        System.Console.Write("M", receiveMessageResponse);
            return "true";

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet of code that i use to read a queue try and use it and see if it works

```
static async Task<string> Start()
        {
            string AccessKey = "";
            string SecretKey = "";
            string SQSqueues = "https://sqs.";

            RegionEndpoint Region = RegionEndpoint.

            bool processedSQS = false;
            AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKey, SecretKey);
            var AwsRegion = Region;
            var SQSClient = new AmazonSQSClient(credentials, Region);

            var SQSRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest
            {
                MessageAttributeNames = AttributesList,
                AttributeNames = new List<string>() { "All" },
                MaxNumberOfMessages = 10,
                QueueUrl = SQSqueues,
                VisibilityTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalSeconds,
                WaitTimeSeconds = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalSeconds
            };
            var SQSResponse = SQSClient.ReceiveMessageAsync(SQSRequest);
            SQSResponse.Wait();
            string JsonPass = null;

            if (SQSResponse.Result.Messages.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var Message in SQSResponse.Result.Messages)
                {
                    string SqsMessage = Message.Body;
                    bool CallUpload = await Insert.GetConfig(SqsMessage, credentials, AwsRegion, tableName);

                    if (CallUpload == true)
                    {
                        var deleteRequest = new DeleteMessageRequest
                        {
                            QueueUrl = SQSqueues,
                            ReceiptHandle = Message.ReceiptHandle
                        };
                        var deleteResponse = SQSClient.DeleteMessageAsync(deleteRequest);
                        deleteResponse.Wait();
                    }
                }

            }
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: Another way to do this is to add a trigger on the lambda which will then be automatically triggered by the Sqs if there's new messages, this will be easier because you dont have to read the messages you just use SQSEvent which will contain the message that triggered the Lambda

Answer (score 1):

You can use this two code section to push and pull data from FIFO SQS

Push data -

```
        IAmazonSQS sqs = new AmazonSQSClient(RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast1);

        var sqsRequest = new CreateQueueRequest
        {
            QueueName = "SQSChatFIFOQueue.fifo"
        };
        sqsRequest.Attributes.Add("FifoQueue", "true");
        var createQueueResponse = sqs.CreateQueueAsync(sqsRequest).Result;
        var myQueueUrl = createQueueResponse.QueueUrl;

        var listQueueRequest = new ListQueuesRequest();
        var listQueueResponse = sqs.ListQueuesAsync(listQueueRequest);

        foreach (var url in listQueueResponse.Result.QueueUrls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(url);
        }

        var sqsMessageRequest = new SendMessageRequest
        {
            QueueUrl = myQueueUrl,
            MessageBody = userId,
            MessageGroupId = "test",
            MessageDeduplicationId = "test"
        };
        sqs.SendMessageAsync(sqsMessageRequest);
        return myQueueUrl;
```

Pull data -

```
        var sqs = new AmazonSQSClient(RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast1);
        var queueUrl = sqs.GetQueueUrlAsync("SQSChatFIFOQueue.fifo").Result.QueueUrl;

        var receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest
        {
            QueueUrl = queueUrl
        };

        var receiveMessageResponce = sqs.ReceiveMessageAsync(receiveMessageRequest).Result;
```

Comment: The pull data code worked like a charm, thanks!